# What do I need in order to make a chrome extension that uses the chrome.tab API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Say I want to create an extension allowing me to close a Chrome tab by clicking a tab twice. So, single click displays the page of the tab, double click closes the tab. That's all.

This means I don't require any browser actions, options, or page actions. What would I need besides a manifest.json and how are the Types, Methods, or events for "chrome.tabs" implemented?

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: you **cannot** interact with tabs at that level. The actions that the user makes externally, like double clicking on a tab, or right clicking on a tab, are only controlled by Chrome itself: there are no listeners or methods that can control the behavior of Chrome in this way.

By the way, if you want to create an extension that only uses the [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), then all you have to do is to declare the permissions for it in your `manifest.json`, and also add the `"background"` field, like this:

```
...
"permissions": ["tabs"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
...
```

and then create a `background.js` script that will run in the background page of your extension, without the need of page/browser actions.